# Discretization of Inhomogeneous Dirichlet Boundary Conditions for 2D Poisson's Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let our problem be
$$
\begin{align*}
-\Delta u &= f(x,y), \quad (x,y) \in [0,5]\times [0,5]\\
u(x,y) &= g(x,y), \quad  (x,y) \in \partial\{[0,5] \times [0,5]\}
\end{align*}
$$

Suppose you have a $4\times4$ step mesh grid (for a total of $25$ grid points). Begin the indexing at $i,j = (1,1)$ for the bottom left corner; take a lexicographical ordering from bottom up, then progressing from left to right. So in the equation $Au = b$, where $A$ is $25\times25$, b is $25\times1$.

Then for *inhomogeneous Dirichlet* boundary conditions, what is are the values of $b$ at the corner of the grid and the corner of the *interior* grid? That is, what values constitute $b_1, b_5, b_{21}, b_{25}$ for the corner of the outer grid, and $b_7, b_9, b_{17}, b_{19}$ for corner points of the interior grid (which has $9$ grid points).

I understand the homogeneous case, but I'm a little confused on the non-homogeneous case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I intended to have this as a comment to Kaster's post, but a solution seemed more fit. Note: This is in no way criticizing Kaster's solution or post. In fact, I had the same exact answer as he did, until I decided to investigate further into the wee hours.

The problem with the matrix that is presented in Kaster's solution is that it doesn't handle Dirichlet boundary conditions properly. Notice that you'll in fact double count certain grid nodes, causing the boundary conditions to be Neumann or some sort of mixed boundary condition. Initially, I couldn't get my code$^*$ to run properly -- the $L_2$ error kinked after the first few iterations. [image: Prior to correcting]

But after fixing the matrix, I was able to get a more accurate result of Matlab: [image: L2].

Here, the $L_2$ norm displays proper behavior (strictly decreasing); it does slow down once you iterate enough times.

I'm no differential equations expert, but this is what I believe to be correct.

### Update

Here's what your sparsity pattern should look like. In your matrix, the positions that are supposed to have values are correct. But you have a few elements that aren't supposed to be there. Think about how the finite difference formulation works and where those elements should be.

[image: img]

Comment: What points are double counted? Also, can you post your matrix as well?

Comment: @Kaster I've been meaning to get back to you. I've been quite busy, but as soon as I can, I'll post it!

Comment: Can you write down finite difference equation for the point 7, based on your matrix?

Answer (score 10):

First, let's enumerate values of $u$ at grid points ($u_{ij}$), so that we have only one index, as stated (lexicographical). This procedure is called flattening of the matrix, i.e. matrix $u_{ij}$ becomes row vector $u_i$. So grid points and function values will be

[image: grid]

Simplest laplacian discretization is
$$
\Delta u_i = \frac {u_{i-N} + u_{i+N} + u_{i-1} + u_{i+1} - 4u_i}{h^2} = g_i
$$
where $N$ is a number of points in each direction, so grid is $N\times N$, and $g_i$ is the function value at grid point where $u_i$ is located. You can check with the picture above to see which points are taken. Obviously, equation makes sense only for the points $u_7$-$u_9$, $u_{12}-u_{14}$, $u_{17}-u_{19}$, since other points are on be boundary and they satisfy BC, not PDE.

So if you flatten your function, for the eligible points $7$-$19$ you get a system of equations. As for the missing points, they satisfy boundary conditions, so $u_i = f_i$, where $f_i$ is the function value where $u_i$ is located. So final system looks as below

[image: system]

Comment: BTW, what did you use to create the diagrams?

Comment: That's what I thought! But the notes I have say the mass matrix, $A$, should be a size $25\times25$ matrix, but only consisting of 5-point stencil, not any of the values you have in orange/beige. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @AlanH I used Powerpoint for first picture, and Excel for second. Big rectangle is 25x25 matrix. To discretize Laplacian 5-point stencil is used. It's clear from first picture, where all points involved in stencil highlighted with bigger circles. Values in orange are needed since they cannot be found using Poisson equation – less points are there than necessary. If you have some other matrix, would you post it, please? I worked similar problems many times, so I'm confused too why it's not the same one as you have.

Comment: I updated my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late and probably not a great answer as I don't fully understand how every line but I left comments wherever I could, but here is code written in Matlab for a 2-D case using inhomogeneous BCs for Poisson's Equation. It utilizes the Discrete Fourier Transform which is a highly time efficient tool, far more than say a matrix inversion. I mostly stumbled upon the code and modified it a bit to fit my understanding. For one reason or another, we seem to need to apply odd extensions which I have found to be tantamount to applying a DST-I to the original dataset, but I'll let you take a crack at that at your leisure. I'll leave this here in case you want to use it. The idea is to use a Discrete Fourier Transform to transform the matrix of equations which lets us factor out the solution and we're left with complex constants that we can simply divide out to the RHS and then inverse fourier transforming to get the solution. I left some workings in comments for this. This probably isn't perfect as I have not tested just how flexible this is, so go ahead and use it for as many different Poisson's Equations as you can come up with and hopefully it will work for you.

````
% Use of FFT for FD approximation to u for
%
%      u_xx + u_yy  = 4,  0 < x,y < 1
%      u(0,y) = y^2, u(1,y) = 1 + y^2, u(x,0) = x^2, u(x,1) = 1 + x^2
%
%  with h = 1/8. This eqn has exact solution uex = x^2 + y^2
%  For simplicity, this script uses FFTs in both directions, rather than 
%  an FFT in one direction and a tridiagonal solver in the other.
%  Note that u_{i,j} corresponds to ROW i and COLUMN j of a matrix of u's;
%  to see the gridpoint values in their correct geometrical orientation
%  so increasing x runs to the right and increasing y upward, 
%  you must display u(:,m:-1:1)'.  Note that in this case, the FD method
%  has zero truncation error since u is parabolic, so the FD soln is exact.
%  Script makes a surface plot of u at the interior grid points.

  L = 1;        % Domain size
  Ne = 2^5;      % Extended-domain gridpoints...should be a power of 2
  h = 2*L/Ne;   % Grid spacing
  m = Ne/2 - 1; % Number of interior gridpoints in original domain

  x = h*(1:m);
  y = h*(1:m);
  
  f = 4*ones(m,m);
  
  % Correct for Dirichlet BCs
  u0y = y.^2;
  u1y = 1 + y.^2;
  ux0 = x.^2;
  ux1 = 1 + x.^2;
  % Neumann BC is a derivative and the finite first order
  % derivative is (f[n+1]-f[n-1])/2h centered difference. so I think it should be
  % f() = f() - BC/2h or f()2h-BC. I have NOT tested for a Neumann BC
  f(:,1) = f(:,1) - ux0'/h^2; 
  f(:,m) = f(:,m) - ux1'/h^2;
  f(1,:) = f(1,:) - u0y/h^2;
  f(m,:) = f(m,:) - u1y/h^2;
  %% Odd Extension. Where 0s are placed can vary from case to case!
  % Google "Discrete Sine Transform" and the Wiki page should provide information for
  % how to apply odd extensions for case-to-case 
  g = [zeros(m,1), f, zeros(m,1), -f(:,m:-1:1)];    %  Odd extension of f in x
  g = [zeros(1,Ne); g; zeros(1,Ne); -g(m:-1:1,:)];  %  Odd extension of g in y
  %% END 
  ghat = fft2(g);
  [I, J]  = meshgrid(0:(Ne-1),0:(Ne-1));            %  New finite indices after extension
  omega_x = 2*pi/Ne * I; omega_y = 2*pi/Ne * J;     %  Convert finite space into Fourier Space: 
                                                    %  omega_indice = 2pi/(number of elements along dimension) * indice
  %% Formulation
  % u_xx = (u[n+1]-2u[n]+u[n-1])/h^2 
  % F() = (sum_-inf+1^inf+1 u[n+1]e^{-j\omega_x(n)} - 2*sum_-inf^inf
  % u[n]e^{-j\omega_x} + sum_-inf-1^inf-1 u[n-1]e^{-j\omega_x(n)})/h^2
  % = (sum_-inf^inf u[n]e^{-j\omega_x(n-1)} - 2*sum_-inf^inf
  % u[n]e^{-j\omega_x} + sum_-inf^inf u[n]e^{-j\omega_x(n+1)})/h^2
  % = (e^{-j\omega_x}-2+e^{j\omega_x})/h^2 * X(e^{j\omega_x}) 
  % = -4/h^2 * sin^2(\omega_x/2)
  % u_xx + u_yy = (-4/h^2 * sin^2(\omega_x/2) + -4/h^2 *
  % sin^2(\omega_y/2)) X(e^{j\omega_x},e^{j\omega_y})
  % u_xx + u_yy = mu * X(e^{j\omega_x},e^{j\omega_y}) 
  %% End Formulation
  mu = -(4/h^2)*(sin(omega_x/2).^2 + sin(omega_y/2).^2);%  mu is just a constant
  mu(1,1) = 1;   % Avoid 0/0 division; vhat(1,1) is known a priori to be 0
  v = real(ifft2(ghat./mu));
  u = v(1:(m+2),1:(m+2)); % Extract u(i,j) from its odd extension
  
%  Plot out solution in interior and print out max-norm error

  [X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
  uex = X.^2 + Y.^2;
  err = abs(u(2:(m+1),2:(m+1)) - uex); 
  err = norm(err(:),inf);
  surf(X,Y,u(2:(m+1),2:(m+1)))
  xlabel('x')
  ylabel('y')
  zlabel('u')
  title('FD/FFT for 2D Poisson Eqn')
  
  %% Alternatively you can use DST to obtain same result without odd extensions
```
````